# How to call a SOAP web service with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap

I'm trying to call a SOAP web service. I tried it in soapUI and it works well, so I know it's a problem in my very simple code mixed with my lack of understanding of it.

When I press the "test" button which should call "signOn", I get no responses whatsoever.
I think that my problem is more of a jQuery issue rather than a SOAP call issue since the SOAP piece works already in soapUI.

This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(data, status) {
        alert(data.d);
    }

    function signOn() {
      // build SOAP request
      var username = 'admin';
      var password = 'mypass';
      var webServiceURL = 'https://192.168.10.111:8090/services/AdminMgmtService/AdminMgmt';
      var soapMessage = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:omi="http://www.verimatrix.com/omi" xmlns:omit="http://www.verimatrix.com/schemas/OMItypes.xsd">' +
      '<soapenv:Header/>' +  '<soapenv:Body>' + '<omi:signOn>' +
      '<userAttributes>' +
      '<omit:userName>' + username + '</omit:userName>' +
      '<omit:password>' + password + '</omit:password>' +
      '</userAttributes>' + '</omi:signOn>' + '</soapenv:Body>' + '</soapenv:Envelope>';
      $.ajax({
        url: webServiceURL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapMessage,
        processData: true,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
      });
    }
    </script>
    <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="test" onclick="signOn();" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
<html>
```

Firebug return response:

```
OPTIONS AdminMgmt

200 OK

192.168.10.111:8090

0 B

192.168.10.111:8090

Response Headersview source
Allow   GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length  0
Date    Mon, 10 Dec 2012 02:18:52 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He...    content-type
Access-Control-Request-Me...    POST
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Host    192.168.10.111:8090
Origin  null
Pragma  no-cache
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you see in firebug to check if there is an Error code being returned? Or what sort of response is server sending back to you?

Comment: hi Thanks for the reply. Let me put the return I get from firebug. That's what confuses me the most actually.

Comment: I think you should look into this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683350/call-soap-xml-web-services-with-jquery-ajax-minified-implementation